# ASP .NET y el Diseño Orientado al Dominio

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, ddd

Estoy desarrollando una pequeña aplicación con una estructura orientada al dominio. El diseño parte de una aplicación de un ejercicio anterior que tenía el patrón `MVC` que viene como plantilla en `.NET`.

Para este ejercicio me he empapado de toda la teoría que he podido, soy Javero y estoy de prácticas en una empresa más perdido que las 7 bolas de dragón. Os pongo en canción un poco para ver si me podéis orientar a los pasos que tengo que hacer.

Tengo que manejar dos modelos, uno es `Restaurante` y el otro es `Valoraciones`. Suponemos que restaurante en terminos de dominio es un `AggregateRoot`. El diseño de esta aplicación se tiene que componer de las siguientes características:

- **Vistas** en capa de presentación (Había pensado en un `MVC`)
- **Api Web**. Aquí tengo un proyecto con la plantilla `ApiWeb 2` + `MVC`.
- **Autenticaciones individuales**. Aquí no se como hacerlo puesto que la lógica va tanto en la capa de presentación como en la de infraestructura.
- **Utilizar** `IoC` **y** `UnityContainer` los cuales se como van pero no se implantarlos en una app real.
- **Modelos** que crean la base de datos `CodeFirst`. Tengo la capa de infraestructura con una biblioteca de clases, pero no tengo ni idea de como hacer migraciones.
- **Repositorios** que gestionen las acciones del `ORM` desde Infraestructura.

### Estructura provisional del proyecto

La disposición de las capas, tras ver un millón de tutoriales cada uno de su padre y su madre me queda así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Podemos ver que `Infraestructura`, en concreto el `repositorio`accede a dominio del cual saco interfaces. `Aplicacion` accede con referencias al `Dominio` y a `infraestructura` con la idea de crear los objetos de dominio e inyectarlos al repositorio. Y `Presentacion` consume la `Web Api` que crearé en el futuro.

### Clases de Dominio

**RESTAURANTE**

```
public class Restaurante : IAggregateRoot
{
    public Restaurante()
    {
        Valoraciones = new HashSet<Valoraciones>();
    }
    public int RestauranteId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public double Avg { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Valoraciones> Valoraciones { get; set; }

    //Aniadir valoracion nueva
    public void AddValoration(Valoraciones v)
    {
        Valoraciones.Add(v);
        AvgRefactor();
    }

    //Nota media
    private void AvgRefactor()
    {
        Avg = this.Valoraciones.Average(e => e.Rating);
    }
}
```

**VALORACIÓN**

```
public class Valoraciones : IAggregateRoot
{
    public int IdValoracion { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string ReviewerName { get; set; }
    public int RastauranteId { get; set; }
    public virtual Restaurante Restaurante { get; set; }
}
```

**INTERFAZ AGREGADO**
Simplemente pretendo marcar una clase para que pueda ser utilizada en repositorios.

```
 public interface IAggregateRoot
{
}
```

**INTERFAZ REPOSITORIO**

```
 public interface IRepository<T> where T : IAggregateRoot
{
    //IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; }
    IQueryable<T> AsQueryable();
    IEnumerable<IAggregateRoot> GetAll(); //Recuperar todo
    IEnumerable<IAggregateRoot> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> esp);//Busqueda con Linq
    T GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> esp); //Recuperar todo con Linq
    T FindById(int? Id); //Buscar por ID
    void Add(IAggregateRoot entidad);//Si no funciona cambiar IAgregateRoot por <T>
    void Update(IAggregateRoot entidad);//Actualiza
    void Delete(IAggregateRoot entidad);//Elimina
    void Save();//Guardar usando SaveChanges()
}
```

### CLASES INFRAESTRUCTURA

**DB CONTEXT**

```
 public class ModelContext : DbContext
{
    public ModelContext()
        : base("name=ModelContext")
    {
    }
    public virtual DbSet<Restaurante> Restaurantes { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ValoracionesRestaurante> ValoracionesRestaurantes { get; set; }
    public static ModelContext Create()
    {
        return new ModelContext();
    }
}
//Este metodo no se si va aqui, la aplicacion ha de implantar la autenticación
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Tenga en cuenta que el valor de authenticationType debe coincidir con el definido en CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Agregar aquí notificaciones personalizadas de usuario
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

**MODELOS EF6 CODE FIRST**

**Restaurante**

```
 public class Restaurante
{
    public Restaurante()
    {
        Valoraciones = new HashSet<ValoracionesRestaurante>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int RestauranteId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Nombre Restaurante")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Ciudad")]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "País")]
    public string Country { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Nota media")]
    [DefaultValue(0)]
    public double Avg { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ValoracionesRestaurante> Valoraciones { get; set; }
}
```

**ValoracionesRestaurante**

```
public class ValoracionesRestaurante
{
    [Key]
    public int IdValoracion { get; set; }
    [Range(0, 10)]
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Nota")]
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Comentario")]
    public string Body { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Nombre Crítico")]
    [DefaultValue("Anonimo")]
    public string ReviewerName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "RestauranteRating")]
    public int RastauranteId { get; set; }
    public virtual Restaurante Restaurante { get; set; }
}
```

**REPOSITORIO**
Falta implementar la logica en los métodos. El acceso a DbContext lo tengo como en un ejemplo de internet, pero no creo que sea válido. Las clases me llegarían desde `Dominio` ¿Dónde debería hacer el mapeo?

```
public class Repositorio<T> : dom.IRepository<T>, IDisposable where T : dom.IAggregateRoot
{

    private readonly DbContext _contexto;
    //private ModelContext db = new ModelContext(); 

    //Es posible que necesite una conexion por parametros
    public Repositorio()
    {
        _contexto = new ModelContext() ;
    }

    public void Add(IAggregateRoot entidad)
    {
        if(_contexto.Entry<IAggregateRoot>(entidad).State != EntityState.Detached)
        {
            _contexto.Entry<IAggregateRoot>(entidad).State = EntityState.Added;
        }
        else
        {
            //db.Restaurantes.Add(Mapper.Map<dom.Restaurante, ent.Restaurante>((dom.Restaurante)entidad));
            _contexto.Set<IAggregateRoot>().Add(entidad);
        }
    }
    public IQueryable<T> AsQueryable()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public void Delete(IAggregateRoot entidad)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public IEnumerable<IAggregateRoot> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> esp)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public T FindById(int? Id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public IEnumerable<IAggregateRoot> GetAll()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public T GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> esp)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public void Save()
    {
        _contexto.SaveChanges();
    }
    public void Update(IAggregateRoot entidad)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**MAPPING**

```
class Mapping
{
    public void CreateClassMap()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
            cfg.CreateMap<ent.Restaurante, dom.Restaurante>();
            cfg.CreateMap<ent.ValoracionesRestaurante, dom.Valoraciones>();
            cfg.CreateMap<dom.Valoraciones, ent.ValoracionesRestaurante>();
            cfg.CreateMap<dom.Restaurante, ent.Restaurante>();
        });
    }
}
```

### PREGUNTAS

¿Cómo puedo almacenar correctamente los modelos desde el repositorio? Recibo clases que implantan `IAggregateRoot`, supongo que habrá que guardarlas mapeando de un modelo de dominio a uno de EF6 y usando el DbContext para almacenar.

¿Cómo hago las migraciones? La base de datos todavía no se ha creado.

¿Cuáles son un poco las pautas y siguientes pasos que he de hacer en cada una de las capas para pasar la información y persistirla en la base de datos.

Gracias y disculpen si falta información o deberían ser obvias algunas cosas, soy nuevo en .NET y vengo de Java y además estoy con dos proyectos. Ya no me dan a basto las neuronas.

Comment: Hola Dani, te recomiendo que dividas tu pregunta en varias mas pequeñas ya que este pedazo monstruo puede asustar a la gente, no digo que este mal tu pregunta pero a menor contenido y mayor especialización de la duda, tienes mas posibilidad de ser respondido

Comment: Disculpa las molestias. La cuestión es que al ser un proyecto entero y poner en situación que es lo que no sé hacer, necesito soltar todo XD. El que está asustado soy yo XD. Gracias por el aviso.

Comment: No te preocupes, estamos aqui todos por lo mismo, para mejorar y aprender, un saludo!

Comment: Aplica el divide y vencerás

Answer (score 1):

Menudo fregado donde te has metido, me costó cerca de un año dominarlo casi del todo, y digo casi porque siempre aprendo algo nuevo.

Si llegas a entender bien el [siguiente esquema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/aa699358.ncapas(es-es,MSDN.10).jpg) entonces se podrá decir que has entendido el concepto de DDD.

Intento contestar a tus preguntas.

**Autenticaciones individuales**: este es un aspecto únicamente de la aplicación, normalmente no forma parte de la lógica de negocio, pero su implementación no es sencilla por así decirlo. Si estás de prácticas y esto sólo es un ejercicio lo más sencillo sería una autenticación externa (Twitter, Facebook, Microsoft, Google, etc...) para así evitar tener que implementar las partes de olvido de contraseña, bloqueo y seguridad, pero luego toca la otra parte que es la autorización, roles, permisos. Si quieres un control total siempre puedes ir por "[ASP.NET Identity](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity)", o por el más reciente "Identity Server" aunque este yo lo he usado en proyectos de .NET Core. Lee un poco sobre los estándares OpenId y OAuth2.0, te vendrá muy bien.

El concepto de la **inversión de control** (IoC) mediante **UnityContainer** básicamente consiste, además de usar el inyector de dependencias, en desacoplar completamente el proyecto de dominio, es decir no tener ninguna referencia hacia las otras capas, de esta forma si necesitas tener acceso a varias bases de datos sólo tienes que modificar el fichero de configuración de Unity sin tener que recompilar el proyecto de dominio. Esto se aplica principalmente en el patrón repositorio, donde el dominio, que por así decirlo es el que manda, indica a través de las interfaces de repositorio lo que necesita, los que lo implementan son los proyectos de datos, por tanto la referencia va del proyecto de datos hacia el de dominio y no al revés. Si no queda claro este concepto dímelo e intento explicarlo más detalladamente. Tienes un ejemplo de implementación con "Unity Container" en [este enlace](https://devonblog.com/software-development/configure-unity-container-config-file/).

Las **migraciones con Code First** no son complejas, una vez lo tengas montado sólo hay que realizar dos acciones, "Add-Migration" que crea el esquema de cambios desde la última migración realizada a los nuevos cambios añadidos, por tanto lleva el versionado de la base de datos y puedes dar nombres a las migraciones, y "Update-Database" que es la ejecución de dichos cambios sobre la base de datos. Tienes más información en [este enlace](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/automatic) para EF6.

Respecto a las **entidades**, bien por la diferenciación entre entidades de dominio y entidades de datos, como te he dicho anteriormente la capa de dominio es la que manda, por tanto el proyecto de BBDD es el que debe amoldar sus entidades de datos a las entidades de negocio, recuerda, el proyecto de datos es el que tiene la referencia al proyecto de domino. Para ello puedes usar [AutoMapper](https://anexsoft.com/tutorial-facil-de-automapper-para-asp-net-mvc) o realizar conversiones de clases manualmente desde el proyecto de base de datos, para ello puedes extender las clases con [clases parciales](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods) a partir de las entidades de datos generadas por "Entity Framework".

Obviamente te surgirán más dudas y probablemente alguien de la comunidad no estará de acuerdo con todo lo que he podido decir aquí y me corregirá, lo cual será bienvenido.

Espero haberte ayudado, suerte.

Comment: Buenos días. Gracias por contestar. Tengo el problema casi solucionado. En cuanto tenga un rato subo todo lo que he solucionado para que lo vean todos. Buen día.

Comment: @DaniGala excelente :D